# ApacheBench on Plesk managed server?

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I call ApacheBench on my server which is managed by Plesk? I have no idea on which URL to enter. I understand that it needs a local address, but which address should I use?

```
ab -c 10 -t 60 http://xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your server www.mypleskmanagedserver.com has an IP of 123.123.123.123

On a *nix box **OTHER** than your webserver type

```
ab -c 10 -t 60 http://123.123.123.123
```

EDIT:
Also it would be useful to mock up some sort of testing strategy.

Find which URLS are accessed most in you web application for example www.mypleskmanagedserver.com/seriouslyheavy.php

and test them accordingly.

If you have an index page that is fairly light and doenst do any heavy processing/db comm it would be misleading to just benchmark your homepage. Mix it up.